# What's the correct way to open an app from a Landing Page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ionic4, deep-linking

I have an app developed in Ionic V4 which uses the deep link plugin, and a landing page developed with HTML and Javascript.

the landing page uses `location.href = "com.orgName.appName://"` to open the app.

The flow is:

a customer receives a link via SMS and when he clicks it he is redirected to a Landing page.

The landing page checks the operation system (Android or IOS) and then checks if the app is installed on the phone. If it is, it opens it and if not it takes the customer to the App Store/Google Play.

This used to work up until not long ago. now, it says "Redirect Blocked".

I read some articles and found out Chrome blocks the redirect on page load, so you need to create a button for the user to click, and then it works.

Our customer insists that the app/store will open without the user interaction.

I found an app which does that successfully, but I can't inspect to see how they did it because the logic is done on their server.

I've tried:

1. using `location.href` on page load or on load events
2. wrap the redirection in a `SetTimeout`
3. use `window.open` which works for the most part, but not on all devices + requires the user to allow popping windows.
4. using `document.getElementById` on a button, and invoking the `click()` function

Comment: Try a `<meta>` redirect or even a server-side redirect

Comment: meta worked for IOS but not Android.
After a long struggle I gave up and decided to create a simple ASPX page that uses Response.Redirect and it works like a charm